# "The program 'rails' is currently not installed" after git clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm a beginner with rails and git (and stackoverflow) so I hope being explicit.

I want to git clone my rails app from github, so what I've done is :

```
    $> mkdir old
    $> cd old
    $> git clone git@github.com:Project_name/webapp.git
    $> cd webapp
```

Everything works fine during `git clone` but when I do `cd webapp` I'm not having the rvm message `You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not compatible with other ruby managers` that I normally have.

Moreover, when I run `rails s` an error occurs :

```
    $> The program 'rails' is currently not installed
```

So my questions are how to tell rvm to manage my clone project and how to link rails with it ?

EDIT:

In response to Vecchia Spugna : RVM is installed into my machine and I have many .rvmrc file after git cloning like .rvmrc.03.26.2013-15:22:31 however I do not have a simple.rvmrc

Comment: do you have rvm installed in your machine? do you have the .rvmrc file after the clone? (maybe it's ignored by git)

Comment: Try to follow these steps again https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: Please answer your own question and then accept the answer. This is showing as an unanswered question. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the .rvmrc file is not sent on github, so I copied my .rvmrc file from an old version of my app and everything works fine